# How to automate clicks on elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I got a lot of saved posts/comments on reddit(seems to be like a thousand), and wondered how I would go about unsaving them, without clicking unsave on everyone of them.

This is my approach so far:

I right-clicked on the `Unsave` button of a post and clicked Inspect to find out the class-name,
which I then used to analyse how many posts have that button:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("_10K5i7NW6qcm-UoCtpB3aK _3tRpmsTw--cwH6_MAO3ZOm _3yh2bniLq7bYr4BaiXowdO _2sAFaB0tx4Hd5KxVkdUcAx _28vEaVlLWeas1CDiLuTCap")
```

That results in an array, and I would now go further and save this in a variable to run a function with an click-event on it:

```
var buttonInstances = document.getElementsByClassName("_10K5i7NW6qcm-UoCtpB3aK _3tRpmsTw--cwH6_MAO3ZOm _3yh2bniLq7bYr4BaiXowdO _2sAFaB0tx4Hd5KxVkdUcAx _28vEaVlLWeas1CDiLuTCap")

buttonInstances.someClickFunction()
```

Thing is, (besides me not knowing exactly what `someClickFunction()` should do), the save button seems to have the same class. How would you go about this? I've seen some solutions, but the code seems deprecated, and I am just keep copying and pasting and getting errors.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction, and maybe on the way I could collect some further knowledge about `let` and `var`,  and why I should use arrow functions etc...

I hope this should convince you that I have at least tried something by myself.

Comment: You need something like `[...buttonInstances].forEach(button => button.click());`but this will click all buttons. You need to make sure that `buttonInstances` contains the correct buttons first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier on old reddit - the elements are quite predictably named. `link-unsave-button` is the class name of `<li>`s which are parents of unsave buttons for links, and `comment-unsave-button` is the class name of `<li>`s which are parents of unsave buttons for comments.

So, with the selector string

```
.link-unsave-button > a, .comment-unsave-button > a
```

you can iterate through all of those `<a>`s and `.click()` them.

Because each click requires a network action, you should probably add a delay between each one, say, 500ms:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
(async () => {
  for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('.link-unsave-button > a, .comment-unsave-button > a')) {
    a.click();
    await delay(500);
  }
  console.log('done');
})();
```

This removes all saved links on your `/saved` page, when you're on old reddit. (Yes, I tried it myself, it works)

You could probably do something similar on new reddit (just by using the selectors on new reddit instead), but the class names may vary (on my device, they're different from yours), you may have to re-examine the DOM and change the code in some circumstances, which isn't great. Better to do it from old reddit.

Comment: Hey thank you @Chris G! and @CertainPerformance, this works for me too. I just tested it on the reddit home button, rewritten your code a little bit:

`const delay1 = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
(async () => {
  for (const a of document.getElementsByClassName('_30BbATRhFv3V83DHNDjJAO')) {
    a.click();
    await delay(500);
  }
  console.log('done');
})();`

There are some issues, like having to rename the const delay after each function run, but i'm tackling that as well as modifying the code for other elements.